# I am having an Xml parse Exception when i am downloading a file in pdf format

Tags: java, xml

When ever i try to download the file it shows that its downloading but shows that 0 bytes is downloaded. When i checked the log it showed the following :-

```
2015-09-03 05:04:37,503 [http-nio-8463-exec-4] ERROR 
document.XhtmlDocumentServi ce - caught xml parse exception for xhtml:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/x html1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
```

This is happening in some systems ,while in some system the downloading process is working file.

Can  i add something to the html file i created so that this is resolved?

I have tired adding a `defaultCodec="html"`. Also is it because of the javascript ive used in the file?

NOte: Actually i am writing an html file , that has to be downloaded in the pdf format.

Comment: You are sending pdf file but in header you are saying it is xml or html

Comment: Actually i am writing an html file , that has to be downloaded in the pdf format. Sorry if i didn't make myself clear.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.* Your explanations are confusing. Are you downloading, or writing? PDF or HTML? And there is no single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the real problem was, While pulling the data the  "&" that i was writing in my html file was taken as a normal html character but if "&" was being pulled from the database it showed the above error.Basically the & that was being called was taken as a jvascript by the parser and so the exception was being thrown.